# How to SUM only a single value of a repetitive field foreach loop in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, sum, calculated-field

I want to change the value of a total amount according to the other field inouts which are in a loop or same fields name.

This is my form.

```
<?php
    $sudentname = $_POST['sudentname'];
    $admissionnmbr = $_POST['admissionnmbr'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
?>
<form method="POST" action="/" >
    <table class="paymentConfirmTblMutiSt">
        <tbody> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Admission No</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        <?php
        foreach($sudentname as $key => $v){
            $totalAmount +=$amount[$key]; // to sum all of amount
        ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sudentname[]" value="<?= $sudentname[$key] ?>"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="admissionnmbr[]" value="<?= $admissionnmbr[$key] ?>"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="inputChangeVal" value="<?= number_format((float)$amount[$key], 2, '.', ',') ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    Total payable : <input type="text" name="totalAmount" value="<?=number_format((float)$totalAmount, 2, '.', ','); ?>" class="totalAmount"/>
</form>
```

so this is showing the amount and details of the students according to their name and admission number which were filled up in a previous form.
This is how this will look if the user pays for two students: http://prnt.sc/eh0ygd (I did not show all the fields in the code above)

Now if the user wants to change the amount of student he can just click on the fields and change it becuase these are text inputs.

My issue is when the user updates the '`amount[]`' this should be **calculted (SUM)** and should be dispalyed in the '`TotalAmount`'
Since this value / name of the fields are in a loop or in same name I am confusing how to do this.

for live changes following code works fine.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        function updateTotal()
        {
            var price = parseFloat(jQuery(".inputChangeVal").val());
            var total = (price + 1) * 1.05; // I want to change this line to SUM the Amount[]
            var total = total.toFixed(2);
            jQuery(".totalAmount").val(total);
        }
        jQuery(document).on("change, keyup", ".inputChangeVal", updateTotal);
    });
</script>
```

I just checking the var total with another calculation.
This one changes the value in 'totalAmount' lively while the user makes changes in `'inputChangeVal'/ in amount[]`

What I want is SUM the `amount[]` and show that in `'totalAmount'` while the user updates the `amount[]` fields

How do I have to update the jQuery for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a jQuery iteration loop on the input field representing Amount

E.g.:

```
Sum = 0;
jQuery("input.inputChangeVal").each(function( index, value ) {
    Sum += parseInt(jQuery(this).val()); //index represents the number of input (array elements 0, 1, 2, etc.)
    });
jQuery(".totalAmount").val(Sum);
```

Sum will now represent the Sum of the values in the Amount input fields

Comment: You are iterating through a string: `"input[name='amount']"`.  The first element is `i` and the last one us `]`.

Comment: The jQuery each function will take care of the iteration represented by 'i' in your comment

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren thanks for that.. this is how I've updated the code now : https://paste.ofcode.org/Bi4QKsaKktL4u5rmYA4amM but I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in input.inputChangeVal`

Comment: Oke, depends on your configuration, I updated above code try it again

Comment: thanks.. function works now.. but not sure it is SUM ing or adding.. this is the out put now : http://prnt.sc/eh1bvq  when I try to change `5` to `50`

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren  
thanks.. function works now.. but not sure it is SUM ing or adding.. this is the out put now : prnt.sc/eh1bvq when I try to change `5` to `50`

Comment: What do you mean with sum vs. adding? You reset sum to 0 on function trigger. Than all values will be added to sum, which represents the sum of all the values?

Comment: I am not sure man @TVAvanHesteren.. let's say I want to SUM `1` and `2` .. if I use your code the ou put is `01.002.00` (kind of adding) if I use @KennyDope 's answer the output is `3` - SUM ing

Comment: Ah I understand your question, jQuery interprets the number as a string. Make sure you offer the number as a value, or use parseInt(), see updated answer

Comment: It gives total amount `NaN`

Comment: Are all the Numbers integers or not?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        function updateTotal()
        {
            var price = 0;

            jQuery(".inputChangeVal").each(function(){
                 var t = parseFloat( $(this).val() );
                 price = price + t;
            });

            var total = total.toFixed(2);
            jQuery(".totalAmount").val(total);
        }
        jQuery(document).on("change, keyup", ".inputChangeVal", updateTotal);
    });
</script>
```

Edit: removed line and radix param from parseFloat...

Comment: This works.. but I do not think that this is the perfect way. why you are using `10` in `var t = parseFloat($(this).val(), 10);` and I want only SUM.. nothing else.. so I've removed `var total = (price + 1) * 1.05; ` and updated a line to `var total = price.toFixed(2);`.. so now it works as how I wanted with these changes.. 
update your answer.. I'll accept..

Comment: Changed as requested :)